# Simple Regular Expression that detects strings that start with a z, but not zz

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I'm sorry if this sounds amateur (and for many of you this will) but I'm in a rush, and I thought I'd leverage the wonderful brains of this community rather than attempting to create and expression that does not work.

I need to achieve the following in MySQL!

In a certain field, if the string starts with a z, pick them up in teh SQL statement, but NOT if it's followed by another z. This only applies to the beginning (^) of the string. Case insensitive. So if the string is already "zz_fdfad" that should not be picked up, but anything with "zfda" should be picked up. Also, if the z is followed by anything other than an alpha numeric value, they should be NOT picked up (so I do NOT want results that are like "z_fdfdsa" or "z-fdfsdaa", or "z@fdfds".. you get the idea).

All this while keeping in mind I need an SQL statement for this in MySQL, and it will be processed in PHP.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL

```
col Like 'z%' and not col like 'zz%'
```

It's even index friendly!

Comment: +1 for index friendly LIKE instead of a regex. I'd probably put parentheses around the second clause, just in case: `and not (col like 'zz%')`

Comment: @Ken // *laughs* when MySQL gets `not col like` wrong is when I jump ship. But I'd put parenthesis around the whole though, in case someone does and `OR` somewhere against this lot

Comment: That was easy enough! I'm kicking myself for not thinking of this. When I voted your answer UP, some pink pony started dancing beside it. Is that normal behaviour? hehe

Answer (score 1):

This will match anything starts with a Z and has a non-Z alphanum after it:

```
^z[A-Ya-y0-9]
```

Comment: Thank you for this - the above MySQL statement-based answer was easier to use in this situation, but this certainly is something I will remember in the future. Thank you.